# SQL join 2 tables with conditons on other tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Hello Guys i am fairly new in the databases.

I have 2 tables

```
1 Tbl_name     
 ID   - Varchar
 Name - Varchar

2 Tbl_ref
  ID  - Varchar
  Fid - Varchar
```

I want to get Names from `Tbl_name` if `Fid from Tbl_ref = '111-11'`

any help welcome :)

Comment: Specify the relation between two tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 SELECT N.NAME
    FROM Tbl_name N 
            INNER JOIN Tbl_ref R ON N.ID = R.ID WHERE FID =  '111-11';
```

try this

Answer (score 2):

With whatever i understand from your question, this is what you are looking for..

```
SELECT N.NAME
FROM Tbl_name N 
        INNER JOIN Tbl_ref R ON N.ID = R.ID AND FID =  '111-11'
```

I would also suggest you to refer to this link..
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name
FROM Tbl_name, Tbl_ref
WHERE Tbl_name.ID = Tbl_ref.ID
AND Fid = '111-11'
```